# Filtering JSON on string attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

I am trying to filter out all objects based on a string attribute like this:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(valid_json); 

data = data.filter(function (el) {
  return (el.name == 'myName');
});
```

This returns an empty array but comparing integers works:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(valid_json); 

data = data.filter(function (el) {
  return (el.price == 1000);
});
```

This will get all objects with price = 1000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: `==` != `===`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_%28%29)

Comment: why are you parsing a valid json? and can you post that json?

Comment: It should work as expected. Maybe you don't have a 'name' property in your objects or there's no object with name 'myName'

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid json then you don't have to parse it to create a valid json. That should only be done when you have a valid json string like:

```
var jsonstr = '{"name":"Foo", "price":"1000"}'; // this one needs parsing.
```

Reasons would be for empty Array might be you are targeting the wrong value of a key of the object or the value doesn't exist in the objects you have.

Actually this is working for me:

```js
var data = [{name:"Foo", price:1000}, {name:"Bar", price:1000}]; 

data = data.filter(function (el) {
  return (el.name == 'Foo');
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(data) +'</pre>';
```